# How often do items and zombies spawn?

Tags: unturned

(Primarily asking about the single-player mode)

I know that when I disconnect and reconnect, all the zombies respawn (and I believe all the items as well). But while in the game, I've seen items respawn directly in front of me, and previously cleaned-out areas suddenly have zombies again.

What schedule does the game use to spawn zombies and items? Does it vary based on the type?

Answer (score 1):

They respawn when the area is reloaded. That is... If you get far from an area, and come back, the zombies are spawned again. This is true for the normal gaming, but not for Full Moon. When it's Full Moon, the zombies spawn in 3 seconds. Be aware of this!

I have not experienced items spawning in front of me, can you describe better how that happened?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, I'd say a respawn happens every 20 to 30 minutes.  Not sure if it's the same for items AND zombies, but I think it is.